# UITableView some cells not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have run into a strange problem with UITableViews. Some of the cells in my table are positioned to the far right right of the screen, making it unreadable save for the first few characters. When I scroll through the table the affected cells change. I have added a couple of screenshots to help better understand what I'm dealing with.

[Some views are invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42mVd.png)

[Different views are invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnjZg.png)

I have used the following code to populate the table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewCell";
    NewProductCell *cell = [tableView
                           dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                        forIndexPath:indexPath];

    long row = [indexPath row];

    cell.medicineLabel.text = [_medicineArray objectAtIndex:row];
    if([[_medicineArray objectAtIndex:row]  isEqual: @"Alfabetisch"]||    [[_medicineArray objectAtIndex:row]  isEqual: @"Eerder besteld"]){
        [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;
}
```

_medicinceArray is a list of strings fetched from a webserver, I have verified this is not the source of the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have empty strings inside **medicineArray**

Comment: Unrelated but change `long` to `NSInteger`.

Comment: You may need to include your NewProductCell code to get a proper answer.

Comment: Have you registered the cell with the tableview?
Or rather how have you registered it?  
Also what happens if you statically assign a text to the label instead of taking it from the array?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's something wrong with your cell's state. Especially when the cells are not working RANDOMLY.

You should pay attention that the cells are reusable. From your code, I think you want only the cells with value @"Alfabetisch" or @"Eerder besteld" are disabled, others are interactive.

But what really happens?

If you scroll up and down, the disabled cells are moving outside of the view, eventually some of them are reused to act like another cell to show the data that should be enabled, but since there are no codes to enable them, it will keep disabled. As a result, if you try more, all cells are disabled in the end.

So for your question, it may also be the reason for the strange behavior of your invisible labels.

You should check the codes outside of the method(any code to modify the cells or the labels), or the label's auto-layout in the cell in your storyboard.